# Rake generate not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, octopress

I get the following error when I do`rake generate`

```
Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass. Starting Rack on port 4000
directory source/stylesheets
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 87 of /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified
in a future version of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$moz-"#{$experimental-support-for-mozilla} "$webkit-"#{$experimental-support-for-webkit} "$opera-"#{$experimental-support-for-opera} "$microsoft-"#{$experimental-support-for-microsoft} "$khtml-"#{$experimental-support-for-khtml}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.

DEPRECATION WARNING on line 92 of /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified
in a future version of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$ie6-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie6} "$ie7-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie7} "$ie8-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie8}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.

    write source/stylesheets/screen.css

>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
directory public/stylesheets
Configuration file: /home/ubuntu/octopress/_config.yml
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.13/lib/posix/spawn.rb:2:in `require': /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.13/lib/posix_spawn_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_fix2int - /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.13/lib/posix_spawn_ext.so (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.13/lib/posix/spawn.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.3/lib/pygments/popen.rb:2:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.3/lib/pygments/popen.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.3/lib/pygments.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.3/lib/pygments.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:74:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    write public/stylesheets/screen.
```

Before running `compass watch` I reboot my computer and run `compass clean`.

Comment: <strike>Are you using Windows?</strike> I see you are using Ubuntu.

Comment: long shot but I would try `bundle install` in the root directory to see if there is a newer version of octopress or its dependencies.

Comment: https://github.com/octopress/octopress/issues/183    it is the whole errors  i use Ubuntu16.04  thanks to you

Comment: looks to me that the `posix_spawn_ext` shared library is missing a symbol called `rb_fix2init` - this probably indicates that you are missing another native library or that you have a mismatch between versions of things. Going to the latest versions of everything may be painful but is often good in these cases.

Comment: so,what should i do ?  now  i don't know how i do next.  thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

`compass clean` followed by `compass watch`.

If this is still not resolving the problem clean out the sass cache folder and clear & compile.